# Grouping namespaces

Tags: flask-restplus

I was wondering whether the namespaces themselves can be grouped?

Our REST server project has a highly decentralized structure (along the lines of a Redux fractal pattern) and every feature has its own namespace.  This predictably has led to many namespaces, and the swagger page is getting rather full now.

If this is not achievable, I guess we can live with it, or consider emitting only the swagger json to be consumed by the official Swagger UI that we can run in a separate server.  But I'd much prefer a restplus-y solution, since that represents the least amount of code friction.

Comment: What do you mean by grouping namespaces? Is the grouping of methods to each resource not sufficient? Maybe sharing a sense of your API size (# resources, #methods, etc) along with specifics on why it's a problem.

Comment: @dmulter, I have 45 namespaces so far, each of them are feature-centric, and have their own sets of gets, puts, deletes, and posts.  Hope that helps with understanding my dilemma.

Answer (score 0):

The underlying [OpenAPI Specification](https://swagger.io/specification/) has a concept of tags. The namespace feature in Flask-RESTPlus assigns these names as tags for path definitions, so this is how you get the grouping in a Swagger UI. The specification does not offer any hierarchical grouping mechanism, so therefore Flask-RESTPlus doesn't offer any such feature.

You could consider a different strategy for assigning namespaces/tags to create more manageable groupings, split the API across multiple Swagger UI pages/sites, etc. Sounds like there is no way around your Swagger UI needing to render a very large number of API methods, so making it more understandable via general content structuring may be your best approach.